# Generator of function of Markov process

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Let $X_t$ be a Markov process with generator
$\mathcal{A}f(x) = a f''(x) + bf'(x)$.

For $\phi(x)\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$, we define $Y_t = \phi(X_t)$.

Definition of generator is as follows

$ \mathcal{A}f(x) := \lim_{t\downarrow0}\frac{\mathbb{E}[f(X_t)|X_0 = x] − f(x)}{t}$.

Using definition of generator find generator of $Y_t$?

Any ideas?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: If $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism $\mathcal{A}'f=(\mathcal{A}f\circ\phi)\circ\phi^{-1}$. Using the definition of $\mathcal{A}$ you can explicitely calculate the new coefficients $a'$ and $b'$.